# Python Jupyter Pandas NameError: name 'data' is not defined

Tags: python, jupyter, data-science, nameerror

These are my Libraries

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
```

These are the other one

```
from sklearn import linear_model
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
```

When i try to run this command

```
x = data.iloc[:,:-1]
y = data['Class']
```

this Error is showing

```
NameError Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-13-431e580384e5> in <module>
----> 1 x = data.iloc[:,:-1]
      2 y = data['Class']
NameError: name 'data' is not defined
```

Comment: Where did you define `data`?

Comment: Seems correct to me. Where did you initialize the 'data' variable? You can't just pull stuff from 'data' if you don't create it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You skipped out a step: defining the "data" variable.
I'm assuming your data variable is your dataframe.

This link will help you understand how to load your dataset on python:
https://www.listendata.com/2017/02/import-data-in-python.html?m=1

Comment: Thank you Sir but i just restart the whole project and run every cell again and problem resolve